# My production instance has moved from EU10 to EU41, does the IP change too?

Tags: production, instance, ip

If yes, how can I get the new one?

Comment: See [Where is my Salesforce instance located?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000314281&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1) to find the instance location and then find the [IP addresses here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003652&type=1&mode=1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, each pod has several IP addresses assigned to it, both inbound IPs and outbound IPs. Salesforce recommends that you whitelist their [entire range of IPs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000321501&type=1&mode=1), as these can be dynamically reassigned as necessary. Their main IP addresses for now are as follows:

```
$ nslookup eu41-api.salesforce.com
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    eu41-cdg.cdg.r.salesforce.com
Addresses:  160.8.10.136
          160.8.11.8
          160.8.9.136
Aliases:  eu41-api.salesforce.com
          eu41.salesforce.com
          eu41-cdg.salesforce.com

$ nslookup eu41.salesforce.com
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    eu41-cdg.cdg.r.salesforce.com
Addresses:  160.8.9.8
          160.8.10.136
          160.8.11.8
Aliases:  eu41.salesforce.com
          eu41-cdg.salesforce.com
```